# Check if url exists without checking HTTP response

Tags: ios, http

I have a scenario in which when HTTP status code is not equal to 200 i.e `HTTP_OK` , then I have to make some modifications accordingly.But I do not want to do these changes inside - `(void) connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)` response which is the delegate method of `NSURLConnectionDelegate`.

Is there any other way by which I can find out that URL will not open successfully without checking the response status codes?

Answer (score 1):

You have to check the response code as you do now but instead of doing HTTP GET or POST request you can make HTTP HEAD request to return the headers only without the content. I used to do this to check for broken links retrieved from web in an Android App.

Answer (score 0):

IMO there´s no way to find the information you´re searching for without checking the response.

If you´re trying to keep the check in the actual running main Thread you can use [sendsynchronousrequest](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSURLConnection/sendSynchronousRequest%3areturningResponse%3aerror%3a) to get the response within your actual code block.

But keep in mind, that this will block your main Thread until an Response is returned.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is another way. If you don't want to load all the response, you can kill the request after you received the HTTP code with `[connection cancel]`.

You can also take a look at `didFailWithError` but it does not work for 404 and 500 errors...

Answer (score 0):

A resource identified by a `URL` with a HTTP scheme (`http:`) can be only accessed through a HTTP service. That HTTP service has the power to decide if the resource exists or not depending on HTTP method or HTTP headers (e.g. `Authorization`).

In other words, a HTTP resource cannot be accessed by any other means than through HTTP.

Comment: URIs using the `http` scheme are accessed through an HTTP service. But there are [a couple dozen URI schemes out there](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Official_IANA-registered_schemes) which have nothing to do with HTTP. Just because something looks like a URL does not mean that it is an HTTP resource.

Answer (score 0):

I feel the same way. I handle the response code in `didFinishLoading` or `didFailWithError`.

I just create a property named `lastHTTPResponse` of type `NSHTTPURLResponse`
and set it in `didReceiveResponse`, then handle it later. Set it with each response, so you get the last code and not any redirects (301 or 302).

If you have more than one connection, you will want a property for each.

Sometimes, you want to handle the response early, but when you are calling your own server, most of the time, it's not necessary.